# i can't send http request with header to laravel api on angular 4

Tags: php, angular, laravel-5, httprequest

I am trying to send request with header to my Laravel 5.3 API, using Laravel passport for authentication. The returned header:

> 405 (Method Not Allowed)
>   Response to preflight request
>   doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
>   header is present on the requested resource. Origin
>   'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response
>   had HTTP status code 405.

I have CORS Middleware on Laravel :

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')<br>
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')<br>
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Content-Type, Authorization , X-Auth-Token');<br>
```

and my front-end and api has different address :
   myfrontend.mydomain.com
   myapi.mydomain.com

My Angular HTTP request header is:

```
let headers = new Headers({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',<br>
      'Authorization': 'LaravelReturnedAuthToken',<br>
      'Accept': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',<br>
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',<br>
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS',<br>
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, x-xsrf-token',<br>
});

let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
```

If I remove Angular HTTP request header, everything works.
I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

ApI : Laravel 5.3
Front-end : Angular 4

Comment: `405 (Method Not Allowed)` indicates you need to configure your PHP server to handle OPTIONS requests. Because your request adds `Content-Type: application/json` and `Authorization` headers to the request, that triggers your browser to (automatically on its own) do a CORS preflight OPTIONS request before it tries whatever request you’re making from your own code. And if that preflight fails, then the browser never moves on to trying the request in your code. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests

Answer (score 1):

Just remove those `Access-Control` headers from your request. They are not meant to be sent with request, but rather they have to be returned with the response.

More about this on MDN:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: i changed to : let headers = new Headers({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 
      'Authorization': 'LaravelReturnedAuthToken', 
      'Accept': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 
}); but it doesnt work yet!

Comment: Well you API is probably not configured as you think. You should check this in network tab in chrome, you can see the full request and response headers there. I guess those `Access-Control` headers will be missing in the response. The error you described here says so: `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`